# Failed to open netctl@.service configuration file

Tags: linux, systemd, networkmanager, netctl

I have installed Network Manager, I don't have netctl installed. Whenever I boot my Linux computer I get the following error message:

> systemd[1]: Failed to open configuration file '/usr/lib/systemd/system/netctl@.service': No such file or directory

I assumed this meant that the service was still activated somehow, but by executing `systemctl list-units | grep netctl` I got no results. What is causing this error message?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a stale symbolic link. If it's in `/usr/lib`, it looks like a packaging error unless you did something nasty to the system. But it may well be somewhere in `/etc/systemd`, if systemd is *reading* the link target and using it directly.

Check with `ls -l` or `file` on the path in your question, then on any occurences of *netctl* in `/etc/systemd`. You might also want to examine the logs from the boot time more carefully using `journalctl`.